# FreeImage delete[] bitmap data fails

Tags: c++, visual-c++, delete-operator, freeimage

Please help me with cleaning up my heap after loading bitmap with FreeImage. 
Somehow 
`delete[] data;`
causes `_ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData))` assertion, and I cannot found how to fix it other than commenting this line. Will there memory leak?
Any help and explanation will be appreciated!

Full code at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dWxz0tjM

Visual Studio 2012 solution (with huge FreeImage static lib): http://rghost.ru/40322357 (15.7 Mbytes!)

Full code here:

```
#include <iostream>

// FreeImage static linkage
#define  FREEIMAGE_LIB
#include "FreeImage/FreeImage.h"
#include "FreeImage/Utilities.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "FreeImage/FreeImaged.lib")

using namespace std;

static const wchar_t* sk_Filename = L"Test.tga";

// Error handler to use in callback
void FreeImageErrorHandler(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif, const char *msg) 
{
    char buf[1024];
    sprintf_s(buf, 1024, "Error: %s", FreeImage_GetFormatFromFIF(fif));

    cout << buf;
}


// Bitmap loader from FreeImage samples
FIBITMAP* GenericLoaderU(const wchar_t* lpszPathName, int flag) 
{
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;

    fif = FreeImage_GetFileTypeU(lpszPathName, 0);
    if(fif == FIF_UNKNOWN) 
    {
        fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilenameU(lpszPathName);
    }

    if((fif != FIF_UNKNOWN) && FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif)) 
    {
        FIBITMAP *dib = FreeImage_LoadU(fif, lpszPathName, flag);
        return dib;
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Function gets filename and returns bitmap data array, its size and bits per pixel
void GetData(const wchar_t* szFilename, unsigned char* data, unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height, unsigned int& bpp)
{
    FIBITMAP* src = GenericLoaderU(szFilename, 0);

    if(src == 0)
        return;

    FIBITMAP* src32 = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(src);
    FreeImage_Unload(src);

    // Get picture info
    width = FreeImage_GetWidth(src32);
    height = FreeImage_GetHeight(src32);
    bpp = FreeImage_GetBPP(src32);
    unsigned int scan_width = width * bpp/8;

    if((width == 0) || (height == 0) || (bpp == 0))
        return;


    memset(data, 0, height * scan_width);
    SwapRedBlue32(src32); // Convert BGR to RGB

    // Get bitmap data
    FreeImage_ConvertToRawBits(data, src32, scan_width, bpp, FI_RGBA_RED_MASK, FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK, TRUE);

    FreeImage_Unload(src32);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    FreeImage_Initialise();
    FreeImage_SetOutputMessage(FreeImageErrorHandler);

    //Creating bitmap data array (size is unknown here)
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[]; 
    unsigned int width(0), height(0), bpp(0);

    // Loading data here
    GetData(sk_Filename, data, width, height, bpp);

    //Using data here
    cout << width << "x" << height << "x" << bpp << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width * height * bpp/8; )
    {
        cout << "("
        << (unsigned int)data[i] << ", "
        << (unsigned int)data[i+1] << ", "
        << (unsigned int)data[i+2] << ", "
        << (unsigned int)data[i+3] << ")"
        << endl;

        i += 4;
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Cleanup
    delete[] data;  // <-- Breaks with  _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData));
                    // What's wrong here?

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

---EDIT--------------------------------

Okay, first possible solution is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: [How does that compile?](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c31438b6408c37ccb2d458bac3e28859)

Comment: What is this line supposed to do, and how does it even compile? `new unsigned char[]` (you can probably guess where this is going. Your problem is almost certainly that line)

Comment: @jalf, Apparently MSVC compiles that mess. At least VS11 does.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it in VS10 as well, and that also accepts it. From looking at the disassembly, it calls `new` with a parameter of 0

Comment: Compiles with no errors. Works properly if comment delete line. What's problem with 'new unsigned char[]'?

Comment: @Drop, Typically you have to have a size in there.

Comment: @Drop how is it supposed to know how big an array to allocate? You need to specify a size: `new foo[42]` to create an array of 42 foos

Comment: @jalf, chris When passing array to function GetData() its size is unknown. How to make it properly? Must I create array inside function, when size becomes known?

Comment: use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: @jalf Okay, using `vector` solves delete problem, probably as `vector` don't need to be deleted. =) But, here is a new question.  How exactly implement passing dynamic array of unknown size to function if I would like to use only plain arrays? I fight 3rd day with them =) BTW, thank you guys for your replies!

Comment: The answer to that *is* not to use plain arrays. :) That's why `vector` exists. C/C++ arrays are really really *really* primitive. Don't use them if you have (1) dynamic sizing, or (2) you need to pass the data to or from functions.

Comment: Possible `std::vector` solution if someone (will be) interested: http://pastebin.com/jUppcNQx

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the `delete`.

The thing is that Debug Crt Runtime can check the memory integrity only during calls to memory API like: malloc, free, realloc, new, delete.

You have a memory overrun that is detected by the Crt.

Obviously, `new unsigned char[]` does not allocate enough bytes for you.

Move the allocation into the `GetData()` proc and call it like:

```
unsigned char* data = GetData(sk_Filename, width, height, bpp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that calculates the size of data based on the image.

Then allocate data with that size

e.g.

```
size_z GetDataSize(const wchar_t* szFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to calculate the required size inside your `GetData` function, so allocate the array there and return it instead.

You would have

```
unsigned char* GetData(const wchar_t* szFilename, 
                       unsigned int& width, 
                       unsigned int& height, 
                       unsigned int& bpp);
```

which contains

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[height * scan_width];
// Do the conversion...
return data;
```

and `main` would say

```
unsigned char* data = GetData(sk_Filename, width, height, bpp);
```